# Iterate over an ArrayList containing ArrayList

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I am working on a bagging problem. I am given a list of items(ints), and bags that have a maxSize. I am trying to find the least possible amount of bags to fit all the items. I need to do this in a recursive method.

I am storing bag objects (That are ArrayList of integers, with some helper methods of checking if the size + an int will be greater than the maxSize of the bag). I am then storing all of these bags in an ArrayList objects. The problem I am running into is I seem to be adding every item to every bag. Below is the method I believe the problem is. I can't think of a way to exit once I have found I can add the item to the bag at 'i'. At this point I need to get a new item, and try to bag it at the first bag, if it doesn't fit then try the second, third etc.

baggedList = ArrayList ::::
recList = List of ints I am trying to bag

I feel like I am over complicating this. If you have any better suggestions please do tell.

```
    public boolean bagging (ArrayList<Integer> recList){

    boolean keepBagging = true;
    System.out.println("right before the recursive method");
    System.out.println("the reclist before while loop" + recList.toString());

    while (!recList.isEmpty() && keepBagging){
        int item = recList.remove(recList.size() -1);
        for (int i= 0; i < baggedList.size(); i ++){
            System.out.println("i = " + i + " Item = " + item);
            if (tryToBag(item, i)){ //boolean method
                addItem (item, i); //adds the item
                bagging (recList); //recursive call
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("FAILED" + keepBagging);
                keepBagging = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return keepBagging;
}
```

CanBag method that calls a Bag method

```
    private boolean tryToBag(int item, int i) {

    boolean canBag = false;
    Bag currentBag = baggedList.get(i);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = currentBag.getList();

    if (currentBag.canBag(item)){
        canBag = true;
    }
    return canBag;
}
```

canBag method

```
    public boolean canBag(int size){

    if (size + Bag.sum() <= maxBagSize){
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

toString

```
    public String toString(){
    int counter = 0;
    String ret = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < baggedList.size(); i++){
        Bag tryThisBag = baggedList.get(i);
        ret += "bag " + counter + tryThisBag.getList().toString();
        counter++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

addItem method

```
    private void addItem(int item, int i) {
    Bag currentBag = baggedList.remove(i); //removing list
    ArrayList<Integer> list = currentBag.getList(); // new list
    list.add(item); //adding item
    System.out.println ("List here at bag" + i + " : " + list.toString());
    currentBag.setList(list); // sets the arrayList back to the bag object
    baggedList.add(i, currentBag); //sets the bag at the index in the collection of bags

}
```

Comment: Can you tell declaration of this  baggedList .. which.size() u checking in for loop..! also what addItem() do..add in what ?

Comment: ArrayList<Bag> baggedList. Is the declaration. A 'Bag' is just an ArrayList<Integer>. The size() is the amount of 'Bags' I can use. I have initialized it before this method. I am given the amount of available bags. AddItem() takes the 'Bag' out of baggedList by index, and just adds it to that 'Bag' ArrayList.

Comment: Quoting from your question "I am then storing all of these bags in an ArrayList objects." Can't you store these bag objects in a TreeMap with maxsize being a key. Hence the <K,V> with maxsize 1 will have bag that can accommodate values less than or equal to 1. The bag with size 2 can values less than or equal to 2.

Comment: I meant to say "I am storing all of these bags in an ArrayList of Bag objects. The Bag objects are just an ArrayList<Integer>. And I don't think that will work. A bag can have a maxSize of X. Which in turn can store 1 to many items, as long as the total sum of all those items is <= the maxSize

Comment: The least amount of bags = count of list of items / maximum size of the bag. Is a recursive function required?

Comment: @Keystone1722 Can you also post the expected output. i.e how the final array list would look with values of the bag at an index?

Comment: Yes, recursive method is required. Expected output would be for List of items to bag = [3, 2, 1], maxBagSize = 5, and maxAmountOfBags = 2. **Bag0 [3, 2], Bag1[1]

Comment: "The problem I am running into is I seem to be adding every item to every bag".. pls additem () method also.

Comment: @ray by count do you mean 'sum' or amount of items?

Comment: @Neha added the method.

Comment: Ok, i thought your intention was to find the number of bags.

Comment: sorry to ask so many que, donot u think here if (size + Bag.sum() <= maxBagSize) this cond will be always true.

Comment: @neha Bag.sum() returns and int of the sum of everything already bagged. So the sum + size is <= to maxSize I return true. But if not it will return false. I don't think I see any problem there. And no worries on the questions. The more the better.

Comment: I am just confuse .. as u say Bag.sum() gives total baggaed values but which bag ..?? i think it should be currentBag.sum() .. or i m just misunderstanding your class structure.

Comment: @Keystone1722 I am just curious did you find solution to this..?

Comment: @Neha No not really. I scrapped this version and started a new one that takes a different approach. Thank you for questions, and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scrapped this version and started a new one with a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean bagging (ArrayList<Integer> recList){

boolean keepBagging = true;
System.out.println("right before the recursive method");
System.out.println("the reclist before while loop" + recList.toString());

while (!recList.isEmpty() && keepBagging) {
    int item = recList.remove(recList.size() -1);
    for (int i= 0; i < baggedList.size(); i ++){
        System.out.println("i = " + i + " Item = " + item);
        if (tryToBag(item, i)){ //boolean method
            addItem (item, i); //adds the item
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("FAILED" + keepBagging);
            keepBagging = false;
        }
    }
}
return keepBagging;
}
```

I merely just added a break call into your code, it's hard to understand what you are going for. You shouldn't need to recurse with this. If you can try to bag and you add an item, then break and then remove the next item and loop over some more. Is this what you wanted? Or on success, should it continue to the next iteration?

Comment: I am going for - take an item and try to add it to the first bag, if I can't, try the second. If I can't add it to the second, try the third and so on. I eventually want to add all the items to the least amount of bags. I tried adding in your break, and I get the same results. The results were list is [3, 2, 1]. The maxBag size is 5. Output is Bag0 = [3,2], Bag1 = [3,2]. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

For each item in reclist, try to find a slot in bags, if found break out of for loop and move to the next item in the reclist

```
while (!recList.isEmpty()) {
int item = recList.remove(recList.size() -1);
for (int i= 0; i < baggedList.size(); i ++){
    System.out.println("i = " + i + " Item = " + item);
    if (tryToBag(item, i)){ //boolean method
        addItem (item, i); //adds the item
    }
  break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This still gives the same results I have been getting.  The results were list is [3, 2, 1]. The maxBag size is 5. Output is Bag0 = [3,2], Bag1 = [3,2]

Comment: Can you copy your tryToBag() method, that might help!

Comment: I have copied them in. I have also copied my toString.